# Sequelize, one-to-many association, find with include

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, model-associations

I am having trouble understanding why find is throwing errors while trying to eagerly load associations.

Relevant models:

Tag:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Tag = sequelize.define('Tag',
  {
    tag_name: {type: DataTypes.STRING(30), allowNull: false}
  },  
  {
    associate: function(models) {
      Tag.hasMany(models.Event, {foreignKeyConstraint: true});
      Tag.hasMany(models.Retailer, {foreignKeyConstraint: true});
  }   
}); 
  return Tag;
};
```

EventTag:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var EventTag = sequelize.define('EventTag',
  {
    cor_name: DataTypes.STRING
  },
  {
    associate: function(models) {
      EventTag.belongsTo(models.Tag, {foreignKeyConstraint: true});
      EventTag.belongsTo(models.Event, {foreignKeyConstraint: true});

    }
  });
  return EventTag;
};
```

When I do a find I get an error saying "EventTag not associated to Tag!"
Here's the find:

```
db.Tag.find({
  where: ['id = ' + req.param('activity')],
  include: [
    {model: db.EventTag,
     include: [
       {model: db.Event,
        where: [where]}]
    }], 
  attributes: [
    'id',
    'tag_name']})
```

What am I missing here? I have even tried a findAll instead, with the same error.
I am using sequelize 1.7.10, will it help if I get to the latest version?

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue.
I overlooked:

```
Tag.hasMany(models.Event, {foreignKeyConstraint: true});
```

should be instead be:

```
Tag.hasMany(models.EventTag, {foreignKeyConstraint: true});
```